# Bootstrap Navbar wont play animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a bit of trouble getting my animation to play when my Bootstrap 3.3.7 navbar collapses upon scrolling from the top of the page.  If I change the size of other divs in my navbar in Sublime while BrowserSync is active, it will show the animation but still doesn't work when I scroll.  The example I followed was:

http://jsfiddle.net/Filo/m7yww8oa/

and recreating the problem using much of my existing code is:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div>
      <div class="navbar-header" id="header">
        <button id="navbarToggle" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-brand" id="title"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.jpg" /></div>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsable-nav">
        <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right visible-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
          <li><a href="about.html">About US<br><i class="fas fa-users visible-md visible-lg"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="why.html">Why Us<br><i class="fas fa-question-circle visible-md visible-lg"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact<br><i class="fas fa-envelope visible-md visible-lg"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="container-fluid" id="main">
  <img src="images/goldwire1.jpg" id="goldwire1" />
</div>
<div class="container" id="services">
</div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
  <div class="fifty" style="float: right;"><img src="images/probe.jpg" id="probe"></div>
</div>
<div class="info" style="color: #f5f5dc; background-color: #003366;">
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7rqv3m8r/

I can't seem to figure out why my animation won't play.  I can see in my dev tools that .shrink is added once I scroll off the top and the webkit animation is active.  Any help is appreciated, thank you for taking time to check this out.